# how to change subject in whatsapp web using Chrome console

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I was curious about this topic. So I ask myself if i could program a js code in Chrome developer console in order to change the subject of a whatsapp web group.

Answer (score 0):

so I write the code that I use to play a little with the subject:

```
f = function(){
    a = document.querySelectorAll("[data-icon='pencil']")[0];
    a.click();
    e = document.querySelectorAll(".copyable-text.selectable-text")[0];
    e.innerHTML = "amistades yanbal et ex";
    //wait
    a = document.querySelectorAll("[data-icon='emoji-input']")[0];
    a.click();
    a = document.querySelectorAll("[data-unicode=''")[0];
    a.click();
    t = document.querySelectorAll("[title='Click to save, ESC to cancel']")[0];
    t.click();
}
i = setInterval(f, 20000);
//clearInterval(i);
```